# How to check live agent availability?

Tags: liveagent

Is there a concise/elegant way to check if a live agent is available? I'd like to show certain elements depending on whether or not an agent is available. The closest thing I found so far was [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25538/liveagent-availability-check), but its from 3 years ago so I'm not sure if it's still up to date, or if there exists a better way of doing so.

Comment: There is a Salesforce documentation here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/live_agent_check_agent_availability.htm

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty Is there an equivalent for web apps?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the chat button code that does that for you.

```
if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
window._laq.push(function(){
liveagent.showWhenOnline('<Chat Button Id Here>', document.getElementById('<Online Element Id Here>'));
liveagent.showWhenOffline('<Chat Button Id Here>', document.getElementById('<Offline Element Id Here>'));
});
```

Comment: What library loads in ._laq and the liveagent object?

Comment: There is code you need to copy from the Deployment as well.